# stop post back when hitting enter on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

Every time enter is pressed the entire page refreshes on the iPad, I want to prevent this from happening.  I have tried every example I have seen and it is not working the ipad.

```
   $('#<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').keyup(function (e) {
       if (e.which === 13) {  
           alert('enter was pressed');  
           e.preventDefault();         
           return false;
       }
   });
```

The alert is working but the page is refreshing everytime, any ideas what to change to make this code work on ipad?

Comment: You will need to prevent the `keypress` event, I'd say

Comment: I thought you couldn't get the keycode from keypress , you can only get it from keyup , is that not true?

Comment: Wait, are you using ASP.NET? I don't see it in the tag.

Comment: @Bergi - put that in an answer - it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess the `keypress` event causes the form to submit, you'd need to prevent that. However, it might be more straightforward to prevent the `submit` event instead of dealing with the confusing [key events](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) (see also [Detecting keystrokes](http://quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)).